# Extraction from string

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code and i am trying to figure a way to make it work like below: string1 contains all the numbers of CPt Codes and String will contain its all Details. I tried using GetToken Functionality but i am still figuring what i am missing here

```
<cfset string = "CPT Codes= 20101 : EXPLORE WOUND CHEST - 06/25/2013,CPT Codes= 20150 : EXCISE EPIPHYSEAL BAR - 06/25/2013,CPT Codes= 2019F : DILATED MACULAR EXAM DONE - 06/25/2013 ">
```

How i can again subside it to make it work like this:

```
<cfset string1 = "20101,20150,2019f">
<cfset string2 = "EXPLORE WOUND CHEST - 06/25/2013,EXCISE EPIPHYSEAL BAR - 06/25/2013,DILATED MACULAR EXAM DONE - 06/25/2013">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, anyone who needs such info can do it like this:

```
<cfset string = "CPT Codes= 20101 : EXPLORE WOUND CHEST - 06/25/2013,CPT Codes= 20150 : EXCISE EPIPHYSEAL BAR - 06/25/2013,CPT Codes= 2019F : DILATED MACULAR EXAM DONE - 06/25/2013 ">
<cfset delimis = "=,:">
<cfset generateLst = ''>
<cfset generateTextlst = ''>
<cfloop list="#string#" index="k">
    <cfset getString = GetToken(k,1,delimis)>
    <cfset getID = GetToken(k,2,delimis)>
    <cfset generateLst = ListAppend(generateLst,getID)>
    <cfset getText = GetToken(k,3,delimis)>
    <cfset generateTextlst = ListAppend(generateTextlst,getText)>        
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#generateLst#" label="ID Input">
<cfdump var="#generateTextlst#" label="Text Input">
```